# How do I load a an unregistered ActiveX dll in PowerShell to instantiate the COM objects it defines?

Tags: powershell, com, activex

I have an application with an API I am trying to reverse engineer to discover the .NET and COM classes it exposes. I am able to load all the .NET Assemblies in PowerShell via

```
ls 'C:\Program Files\MyApp\Bin\*.dll'| %{Add-Type -Path $_.FullName}
```

I can then use reflection to find out all the types, and instantiate them VIA New-Object. However, what if I have a DLL that exposes COM objects, for example a VB6 ActiveX dll. Will [`Add-Type -Path`](http://ss64.com/ps/add-type.html) expose the COM objects in those DLLs, or do I need to Register them with [Regsvr32](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I did COM but ... COM components typically put their metadata in a typelib.  So loading the COM dll into PowerShell probably wouldn't help you much in terms of discovery (unless PowerShell is auto-generating a .NET wrapper assembly).  I would use the .NET tool [tlbimp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to create a .NET wrapper around the COM component.  You would then be able to use [Add-Type](http://ss64.com/ps/add-type.html) to load the generated wrapper and inspect it.

Comment: I guess what I need to do is find a way to determine if a DLL contains COM objects and then do that.